# Conversion of image url as base64 using angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some 500 images which are in the link format contain image as https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT_yOZbW3fwqkqaZiAmwcXTy8ia9hQkbAXKqf6sgLmWfooXUV6qMw.

So in this way i am having some 500 links we i need to convert in the base64 and get printed in the PDF which is generated dynamically.

I have gone through some of functionality

```
function getBase64FromImageUrl(url) {
var img = new Image();

img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');

img.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width =this.width;
    canvas.height =this.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
     return dataURL
   //             alert(dataURL);
};
img.src = url;
 }
```

also i tried

```
function toDataURL(url, callback) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onload = function() {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onloadend = function() {
                callback(reader.result);
              }
              return reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
            };
            xhr.open('GET', url);
            xhr.responseType = 'blob';
            xhr.send();
          }
```

but the problem is as the i am using angular js, its an asynchronous, for converting the image to base64 takes time, i am not able to get those in pdf.

For PDF generation i am using pdfmake.

So, any help to convert the image to base64 faster with less in size.

Please help me, instead of marking it as duplicate or vote down, after providing me the solution go for those.

I am not using any kind of canvas or images that means no relation to HTML for conversion

Comment: You can return the data only when the last image is converted.

Comment: @AsimRaja I have written the angular.forEach to iterate. so for each image it has to return the data

Comment: Then I think it is unclear what you are trying to say, atleast to me.

Comment: @AsimRaja. Thanks. For your responses. Any how i have tried and finally got the solution. Thought its take time to convert, i try to manage with it.

Comment: Great, happy coding.